# SLF4J-LOG4J logging without a log4j.properties file on Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, log4j2, tomcat8

**I hope you can solve this very mysterious puzzle!**

After migrating to Java8 and Tomcat8, the logging info on the servers is ok, but there is no logging information on the developer laptops. Adding Spring-boot-starter-log4j2 there is logging info on the laptops but NOT on the servers. How come? How to fix?

In the parent.pom both the dependencies slf4j-api, the slf4j-log4j binding and the 'slf4j : jcl-over-slf4j' are used. In the project there are no log4j.properites files. In all places where spring boot is used, the spring-boot-starter-logging is excluded.

**Scenario 1:** 
On laptops - the SLF4J combination produces NO logging. I guess that is because there are no log4j.properties files. On the servers this combination shows logging. How can this be? Can there be a **provided** Tomcat configuration that allows this logging?

**Scenario 2:** 
When I add the spring-boot-starter-log4j2, then I get logging on my laptop. On the server there is no logging at all.

Comment: Just adding log4j.properties files for each module?

Comment: Is it possible that a Tomcat server contains extra software that allows for usage of log4j with a default log4j.properties / settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define general logging settings in your tomcat environment. This is for example shown in [this article](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-logging).

In short: (1) add an extra library and (2) add a default log4j.properties file.